# probability of a run of 100 6s in an infinite number of rolls of a die

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

i came upon this problem that i couldn't solve they way i wanted. 
Basically, fair die is being rolled infinitely many times. Prove that the probability of there somewhere being 100 consecutive 6's is 1.

I thought the answer would be like pi, i mean that there are all possible versions of numbers from 1 to 6 (in pi there would be any number combination where numbers are from 1- 9 because it runs infinitely). Could i also say that there is 100 consecutive 6's in pi somewhere, and the probability of it is 1 ? 
I'd like to think that i know the answer to this one, but i can't really prove it.

As it is quite a famous problem , you can also tell me a book where i can find more information how to solve this ?

Comment: Why not start with 2 consecutive 6's? Once you work that out, you can work up to 100.  Do you know where to start?

Comment: Or even just one 6.

Comment: Yeah , for 1 six, it is 1/6 and for 2 consecutive sixes i would use the classical probability interested evets / all events , that would give us 1/36. But i do like the answer from Ross more, it's more intuitive, especially the opposite event probability.  Where would you go from here tho Matthew?

Would you not use the classical probability, but use something else like conditional probability ?

Comment: No, if you roll forever, the probability of one 6 or two consecutive sixes is 1; this is the same as the probability of a run of 100 sixes, but the 100 throws a lot of students off.  So my suggestion was to start with something that appears simpler, solve that, and then you'd see that you could use the same method to handle any number of consecutive sixes.  But Ross took all the fun away by just telling you a way to solve it.  Oh well. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For rolling dice, you can prove the probability is $1$.  One way is to note that the probability that the first $100$ rolls are not all sixes is $1-\left(\frac 56\right)^{100}$, which is very slightly less than $1$.  The chance that rolls $101$ to $200$ are not all sixes is the same, $1-\left(\frac 56\right)^{100}$.  The same goes for each block of $100$  If we now consider $n$ blocks, so the rolls up to $100n$ the chance that we don't have a run from $100k+1$ through $100k+100$ that are all sixes is $\left(1-\left(\frac 56\right)^{100}\right)^n$, which we can make as small as we want by taking $n$ large enough.  I used disjoint blocks just to avoid worrying about overlap, but in fact the chance of having a run of $100$ sixes somewhere rises much faster than this.  For infinite rolls, then, the probability of not having a run of $100$ sixes is zero.  It is still possible that you don't.

For $\pi$, we believe $\pi$ is [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), which implies that there is a run of $100$ sixes somewhere, in fact that they happen at exactly the expected density, but we haven't proven it.

Comment: I do like your solution, but. For 100 6's in a row , i would say that the probability of having all of them 6's is $(\frac{1}{6})^{100}$ and the probability of having not 100 6's would be $1-(\frac{1}{6})^{100}$ . Where this 5/6 comes from, is that having zero 6's in 100 throws ?

Comment: And if we take limit of equation $(1-(\frac{1}{6})^{100})^n$ as $n \to inf$ then it becomes 0. After that , we can say that for infinite rolls the probability of not having a run of 100 sixes is zero and then the opposite of this event is with probability one.